# vim: how to grep from current directory?

Tags: vim, grep

I run `vim .`  in some directory. Inside vim I move to another directory. There I run `:grep` command which searches from the first directory where I run `vim .`. How to configure vim to `:grep` from the path where currently it is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the `<leader>cd` to `%:p:h`mapping too, it is nice.

However for your needs, this line may be better

```
:grep [options] 'pattern' %:p:h/*
```

this will do `grep` from the path of current open file, and keep your real current directory (`pwd`) untouched.

Comment: For the curious `%:h` gives the path relative to `pwd` while `%:p:h` gives the absolute path. More information: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip530

Comment: Can you explain a little more how you set up a shortkey for the `%:p:h` part?

Comment: `:vimgrep /pattern/ %:h/*.js`

Answer (score 6):

You can insert the current buffer's directory through its short form `%:h`. See `:help cmdline-special`.

```
:grep foo %:h/*
```

Alternatively,

```
:set autochdir
```

will automatically change the current directory to the current buffer's directory (so you can just use `.` in each `:grep`). It's a different paradigm, but I find this quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the current working directory. I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`

```
map ,cd :cd %:p:h<CR>
```

Comment: this doesn't help, it is searching from the first position again

Answer (score -1):

You grep in the current location list with the cmd

```
:lv[imgrep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
```

Comment: The OP knows how to grep; his question is around the `{file}` part.

Comment: He asked for how to grep in the current location list.  There is no need to modify your path to do so.  You can use an "l" modifier at the beginning.

Comment: The location list is nowhere mentioned.

Comment: ?? It is implicit: He said he moved to another directory, so issuing :grep searches top-level directory, not the directory he is currently in.